# How do I make an answer able to have more than one word in my java quiz?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a quiz for an assignment in my GCSE computing course, and I need some help. This code compiles but whenever I run the code and input an answer, the answer spills over onto the answer for another question. For example, for the first question if I type the answer as "Mr Someone" when I am running the program, "Mr" becomes the answer to the first question and "Someone" becomes the answer to the second.

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with the sub-strings or what, but please help! :). If you're wondering why the value for the iScore variable is never used, it's because this is not the full code, just the first three questions, the score is printed at the end. There is not difference in the "template" for each question, just a different question and answer.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{
    //creates the Scanners needed
    Scanner szAnswer = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner szPlayAgain = new Scanner(System.in);

    //declares the variables for the answers
    String szFirstAnswer;
    String szSecondAnswer;
    String szThirdAnswer;

    //declares a variable for the score
    int iScore = 0;

    //declares a variable for whether or not the user wants to keep playing
    String szRestart;

    //creates a do while loop, keeps going as long as the user wants to play
    do {
        //tells the user that only one word answers are needed
        System.out.println("Only one word answers are needed!");

        //first question
        //Asks the question and collects the input
        System.out.println("Question 1:");
        System.out.print("Which Ancient Greek god was said to be the god of the sky? ");
        szFirstAnswer = szAnswer.next();

        //converts the answer to a format with the first letter upper case and the rest lower case
        szFirstAnswer = szFirstAnswer.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + szFirstAnswer.substring(1);
        szFirstAnswer = szFirstAnswer.substring(0,1) + szFirstAnswer.substring(1).toLowerCase();

        //prints out the converted response
        System.out.println("You said: " + szFirstAnswer);

        //if the answer was Zeus, the print out correct and add 1 to the score
        if (szFirstAnswer.equals("Zeus")) {
            System.out.println("Correct!");
            iScore++;
        }
        //if the answer was not Zeus, print out a message with the correct answer
        else {
            System.out.println("Wrong! The correct answer was: Zeus");
        }

        //creates a line break
        System.out.println();


        //second question
        //Asks the question and collects the input
        System.out.println("Question 2:");
        System.out.print("Which team has won the most FA Cups since the competition started? ");
        szSecondAnswer = szAnswer.next();

        //converts the answer to a format with the first letter upper case and the rest lower case
        szSecondAnswer = szSecondAnswer.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + szSecondAnswer.substring(1);
        szSecondAnswer = szSecondAnswer.substring(0,1) + szSecondAnswer.substring(1).toLowerCase();

        //prints out the converted response
        System.out.println("You said: " + szSecondAnswer);

        //if the answer was Arsenal, the print out correct and add 1 to the score
        if (szSecondAnswer.equals("Arsenal")) {
            System.out.println("Correct!");
            iScore++;
        }//end if

        //if the answer was not Arsenal, print out a message with the correct answer
        else {
            System.out.println("Wrong! The correct answer was: Arsenal");
        }//end else

        //creates a line break
        System.out.println();


        //third question
        //Asks the question and collects the input
        System.out.println("Question 3:");
        System.out.print("What is the currency of Japan? ");
        szThirdAnswer = szAnswer.next();

        //converts the answer to a format with the first letter upper case and the rest lower case
        szThirdAnswer = szThirdAnswer.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + szThirdAnswer.substring(1);
        szThirdAnswer = szThirdAnswer.substring(0,1) + szThirdAnswer.substring(1).toLowerCase();

        //prints out the converted response
        System.out.println("You said: " + szThirdAnswer);

        //if the answer was Yen, the print out correct and add 1 to the score
        if (szThirdAnswer.equals("Yen")) {
            System.out.println("Correct!");
            iScore++;
        }//end if

        //if the answer was not Yen, print out a message with the correct answer
        else {
            System.out.println("Wrong! The correct answer was: Yen");
        }//end else

        //creates a line break
        System.out.println();

    }while (szRestart.equals("Y"));//end while

    //prints a thank you message to the screen
    System.out.println("Thanks for Playing!");

    //closes the scanners
    szAnswer.close();
    szPlayAgain.close();

}//end main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have szAnswer.next(); you should actually have szAnswer.nextLine(); I believe.

.next() gets the next word that is input, which is why it stops at the first space, where as .nextLine(); gets the whole line when you hit enter.